# Non-Jewish American Woman Married to Israeli Man Going to Israel

Tags: visas, weddings

I met my husband in Peru while traveling.  We went back to California this year and got married.  We are now in Mexico and planning to go to Israel.

So I have 2 related questions:

1) As I understand, American citizens only get a 3-month tourist visa.  I'd like to stay longer, but is there something I can apply for leveraging our marriage?

2) Is there some process we have to do in the Israeli Embassy in Mexico to prove that we are married first before going to Israel?

It all seems so confusing.

Comment: How much longer do you want to stay?  I imagine the answer is different for a four-month stay as opposed to a year or longer.  If you want to move there for six months or longer, or indefinitely, then the question is likely off topic here.  In that case, it should be on Expatriates.SE.

Comment: I'd want to stay like 6 mos like I do in most countries with tourist visas that allow that long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Foreign Office - Consular Services Visa](https://mfa.gov.il/MFA/ConsularServices/Pages/Visas.aspx) page there is no special visa for non Jewish spouses of Israeli citizens.

US-Citizens **do not** need a **B/2 Visitor's visa**:

> A B/2 visa is granted to someone who wishes to stay in Israel for only a short time (for a visit, tourism, a business meeting or study in a Hebrew ulpan). A person who enters Israel on a B/2 visa is not allowed to work in the State of Israel.
>
> A B/2 visa is valid for up to three months from the date of issue. **The duration of the stay in Israel will be determined by the Border Police. A visitor who wishes to extend his visit may submit an application at one of the regional population administration offices of the Ministry of the Interior**.

Assume, however, that the last portion of the statement will apply to you.

---

[Consular services for Israeli citizens abroad](https://mfa.gov.il/MFA/ConsularServices/Pages/Consular_services_Israeli_nationals.aspx)

> **There are several consular matters, that require personal attendance of the applicant at the Consular section:**
> ...
> E. Notification of change in marital status
> ...

A Pdf form [**Notification of Change in Personal Status** (**Marriage**, Divorce, Death of a Spouse)](https://mfa.gov.il/MFA_Graphics/MFA%20Gallery/Consular%20forms/ChangeMaritalStatus.pdf) can be downloaded here.

**Note**:
Such notifications *should* be done at a consulate **nearest** to where a marriage has taken place since the consulate official will be *more familiar* with how marriages are done in their area of responsibility. Should any varification be needed, it would also be easier to do so locally than from any another country.

The consulate official will, no doubt, be able to inform you what further steps are needed to achieve a long term residency in Israel.

Comment: Thank you that was very thorough!  I shall explore the links!